# Deprecated: setlocale(): Passing locale category name as string is deprecated. Use the LC_

Tags: php, gettext

With the new update of PHP coming out it seems they have removed `LC_MESSAGES` and either  `LC_ALL`, `LC_COLLATE`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_MONETARY`, `LC_NUMERIC`, or `LC_TIME` must be used instead, I have changed my `LC_MESSAGES` to `LC_ALL` but am receiving this error:

> Deprecated: setlocale(): Passing locale category name as string is
>   deprecated. Use the LC_* -constants instead

**Here is my code for reference:**

```
public static function gettext()
{
    //include the libs
    include(Config::get('PATH_LIBS')."streams.php");
    include(Config::get('PATH_LIBS')."gettext.php");

    //define all the language settings
    define('LOCALE', 'en_GB');
    define('SESSION_LOCALE_KEY', 'locale');
    define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_GB');
    define('LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM', 'lang');
    define('WEBSITE_DOMAIN', 'messages');

    //check if the language exists
    if(array_key_exists(LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM, $_REQUEST)):
            $current_locale = $_REQUEST[LOCALE_REQUEST_PARAM];
            $_COOKIE[SESSION_LOCALE_KEY] = $current_locale;
    elseif(array_key_exists(SESSION_LOCALE_KEY, $_COOKIE)):
            $current_locale = $_COOKIE[SESSION_LOCALE_KEY];
    else:
            $current_locale = DEFAULT_LOCALE;
    endif;

    //will eventually stick this all in the model file
    putenv("LC_TIM=en_GB");
    putenv("LC_MESSAGES=$current_locale");
    setlocale('LC_ALL', $current_locale);

    //bind it all 
    bindtextdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, Config::get('PATH_MAIN').'lang/');
    bind_textdomain_codeset(WEBSITE_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8');
    textdomain(WEBSITE_DOMAIN);
}
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but why not do what the error says and use `setlocale(LC_ALL, ...)` instead of `setlocale('LC_ALL', ...)`?

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/476)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says "passing locale category name **as string** is deprecated". Look what you're doing:

```
setlocale('LC_ALL', $current_locale);
```

You're passing the locale category as string. Use the predefined constants instead:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, $current_locale);
// Look ma, ^^ no quotes!
```

And if `LC_MESSAGES` is missing, this snippet [from the manual](http://php.net/setlocale) may be relevant:

> - `LC_MESSAGES` for system responses (available if PHP was compiled with libintl)

libintl probably wasn't compiled with your PHP.